# Wiremock test running individually, but not when executing all tests

Tags: spring-boot, junit5, wiremock

I created some integration tests using wiremock. They pass individually, but when I execute the `test` task from gradle they fail with the following error:

```
2022-05-09 11:42:40.077 ERROR 23116 --- [tp1400751713-44] WireMock                                 : No response could be served as there are no stub mappings in this WireMock instance.
```

The special thing about this, it is a Spring ApplicationRunner, so the wiremock has to be ready and stubbed before the test class is initialized
Here is one of my test classes, the other is very similar:

```
@ActiveProfiles({"test"})
@SpringBootTest(args = {"src/test/resources/data/productTestData.xml", "--operation=createProduct"})
@ExtendWith(OutputCaptureExtension.class)
public class CreateProductsFunctionalTest {

  private static final String PRODUCT_CREATE_REQUEST_PATH = "product_create_request.json";
  private static final String PRODUCT2_CREATE_REQUEST_PATH = "product2_create_request.json";
  private static final String PRODUCT_CREATE_RESPONSE_PATH = "product_create_response.json";
  private static final String PRODUCT2_CREATE_RESPONSE_PATH = "product2_create_response.json";

  private static final int FLUENT_PORT = 8085;

  @RegisterExtension
  private static final WireMockExtension FLUENT_WM =
      WireMockExtension.newInstance().options(wireMockConfig().port(FLUENT_PORT)).build();

  @BeforeAll
  static void setup() {
    fluentMockAuthentication(FLUENT_WM, OAUTH_SUCCESS_RESPONSE_PATH, OK.value());
    fluentMockGraphQL(FLUENT_WM, PRODUCT_CREATE_REQUEST_PATH, PRODUCT_CREATE_RESPONSE_PATH);
    fluentMockGraphQL(FLUENT_WM, PRODUCT2_CREATE_REQUEST_PATH, PRODUCT2_CREATE_RESPONSE_PATH);
  }

  @DisplayName("when creating product information")
  @Test
  void shouldInvokeCreateProducts(final CapturedOutput output) {
    assertThat(output).contains("Product with ref '00001111' successfully created");
    assertThat(output).contains("Product with ref '00002222' successfully created");
  }
}
```

The stubbing happens in the `fluentMockAuthentication` and `fluentMockGraphQL` methods.

Comment: Are you calling any of WireMock's reset methods at any point in either of those stubbing methods?

Comment: It seems I was chasing the wrong rabbit. I rewrote the test to no use the args from SpringBootTest, so it doesn't need to be stubbed before the application starts.